# Distribute 3 views inside a scrollview evenly

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, scrollview

I've got 3 view inside a scroll view which I would like to distribute over the whole scoll layout. I don't get it to work properly and hope someone sees the problem.

What I would like is within the scrollview:

```
<scrollview>
  <linear or relative view?>
    (filler)
    moneywheels
    (filler)
    timewheels
    timeWheelsText
    (filler)
  </linear or relative view?>
</scrollview>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fil1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/moneyWheels"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0">

            <!-- content -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fill2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/timeWheels"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/time"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding" >

            <!-- content -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/timeWheelsText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="top|center" >

            <!-- content -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fill3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For your layout, is that two different files, or the same one?

Comment: The layout is in one file and is what I've posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout XML file is not valid.  When dealing with XML, you should only ever have one top level tag.  Assuming you want the ad to display below the scrollview, you want something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView ...>
        <!-- Other pieces under scrollview go here -->
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, for your spacers I recommend using just Views, instead of LinearLayouts.  A view will be a lighter weight class and will not use as many resources.   Using the LinearLayouts for the spacing may cause other surprises too.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the LinearLayouts to Views and changing the top level tag solved my problem.